# How do I check if two consecutive numbers (integers) in a list have the same value?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers (with the length of the list stored in a separate variable) and need to check if any consecutive integers are the same and then print a message if they are. How would I do this?

Comment: Save the first value to a variable, then loop through the list check the current value with the variable value, then set the variable to the current value.  Print it out whenever the current value is equal to the variable.  Try to write some code with this logic, then ask a question with the code if you have problems.

Answer (score 2):

try this: Using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> your_list = [4, 5, 5, 6]
>>> for x, y in itertools.groupby(your_list):
...     if len(list(y))>=2:
...         print x, "they are consecutive"
... 
5 they are consecutive
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a recipe for doing this called [pairwise](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) that you might find interesting:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

number_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
print [a for a, b in pairwise(number_list) if a == b]
```

This will display a list of numbers that have pairs as follows:

```
[2, 4, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do by `zip`ping the list with a copy of itself offset by one element:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for x, y in zip(list1, list1[1:]):
    if x == y:
        print x
```

The above code will print `4`.

Or if you also want the index:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for index, pair in enumerate(zip(list1, list1[1:])):
    if pair[0] == pair[1]:
        print 'index:', index, 'value:', pair[0]
```

This will output `index: 3 value: 4`

Answer (score 0):

Really not the most optimized way but always funny:

```
True in [a==b for a,b in zip(l[:-1],l[1:])]
```

and of course:

```
if True in [a==b for a,b in zip(l[:-1],l[1:])]:
    print("message")
```